# Is it considered acceptable practice to have the same identifier #define'd or typedef'ed, depending on compile-time constants?

Tags: c++, types, c-preprocessor, alias, preprocessor-directive

The Intel Math Kernel Library contains this bit of code in a header file:

```
#ifndef MKL_Complex16
typedef
struct _MKL_Complex16 {
    double real;
    double imag;
} MKL_Complex16;
#endif
```

as described [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/mklxe/mkl_userguide_lnx/MKL_UG_coding_calls/Using_Complex_Types_in_C_C.htm) and discussed [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=68261), this struct definition can be over-ridden by the user by writing

```
#define MKL_Complex16 std::complex<double>
```

before the header file is included.  With this line, `MKL_Complex16` is `#define`'d, which means the character string is just replaced with the literal characters `std::complex<double>` everywhere.  If not, it is `typedef`'ed, which gives the compiler more information.

Is this considered acceptable practice?  I guess it must be, since it's implemented by Intel.  But I found it very confusing while trying to debug some code.

Comment: Why would the typedef gives the compiler "more information"?

Comment: Why the arcane mix of C-style strypedefs and C++?

Comment: @KerrekSB: the library supports both C and C++ apparently

Comment: @Mat: If the library is supposed to support C, what's it going to make of `std::complex<double>`??

Comment: @KerrekSB: it supports _both_, probably with the same headers. That `std::complex` trick can be used if you're using a C++ compiler. The strypedef will please a C compiler.

Comment: @Mat: Hmm... I'd probably want a much thicker coating of `#ifdef __cplusplus` in that case... anyway, you're right. Who knows what this might be used for.

Answer (score 3):

This looks insane. I would be *very* reluctant to pass actual code through the build environment. If anything, use a higher-level flag:

```
#ifndef HAVE_STD_COMPLEX
    struct MKL_Complex16 { double real; double img; };
#else
#  include <complex>
   typedef std::complex<double> MKL_Complex16;
#endif
```